# MTM 2012 - Can I create a bug in draft?

Tags: tfs, microsoft-test-manager, tfs-workitem

I have a few defects that I would like to file into Microsoft Test Manager (and consequently into Team Foundation Server), but currently we aren't 100% sure what the expected behavior is, we simply know that something is misbehaving. Until we verify the expected behavior (which may take a while, as we wait for our vendor to get back to us), is there a way to create a bug in draft mode?

As it stands, creating a bug starts off with Status: New, which submits it to my team's triage, and so on. How can I put this bug into Status: Draft?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can customize the bug to include new state for Draft as the following
[image]

Answer (score 1):

My suggestion is to use a WI tag, then modify the query that your triage team uses to exclude Bugs with the Draft tag.

Comment: Or if you migrated to the scrum template you would have New->Approved->  out of the box...